# Responsive wrapper for list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, list

I am trying to make a responsive wrapper. However, I am having issues determining the right height of it. It's basically a list and when the list gets thinner, its children get fatter.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/cmfL2643/1/). Notice doesn't reproduce the problem when you resize the output window, since it just let's the list go out of view. In my actual application, the list stays entirely inside the screen.

This is my attempt, with jQuery:

```
if ($(window).width() < 500) {
    $(".wrap").css("height", 100 * $(".list li").length);
    $(".wrap-list").css("height", 87 * $(".list li").length);
} else {
    $(".wrap").css("height", 70 * $(".list li").length); // every item has 70px height, I guess!!!
}
```

However these hardcoded values are error-prune, since I just figured them out with my eyes in my machine. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you'd like for the list items to get taller as the screen width gets smaller. Best practice is to use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), no JS needed:

```
label {
    padding: 10px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:500px) {
    label{
        padding: 25px 10px;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/cmfL2643/2/

Comment: You are really a webmaster, I will upvote your best answer then too! Notice that I had to add this when the media is "small", `input[type="checkbox"] {
  top: 40px;
 }`, so that the ticking boxes were vertically centerized nicely. Thank you DACrosby!

Comment: Glad to help! If you want to not deal with `top` positioning, [you could move the `inputs` inside the `labels`](http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/cmfL2643/13/). Downside is that to get the strike-though effect, you basically need JS to add a class name to the parent label (although you could [add a `span` next to the `input and use a sibling selector](http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/cmfL2643/14/) I suppose).

Comment: Interesting. However, now I am battling a list (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643639/text-changes-line-on-space/). Maybe another time I will try your suggestion.