# Text changes line on space

Tags: css, html, list, html-lists

I have a list, which leaves some spaces for indentation purposes and also provides dashed underlying. However the `display` properties used for this list do no match, causes the text to change line when a space is found. Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/cmfL2643/16/).

The CSS:

```
.dashed {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    border-bottom: dashed 2px #54687a;
}
li {
    display: table-row;
}
li span {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 1em;
}
```

I tried to keep only one `display` property, but that failed. Anyone has a fix for this please?

---

Let's speak with images!

What happens now - it's the problem:

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `dashed` class, and add these styles:

```
li span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: -12px;               /* compensate for padding-left: 12px; */
  border-bottom: dashed 2px #54687a;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/g3y6y21p/)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get it so that everything is in one line, like this?

> Name: Charis Spiropoulos

If so, try this:

```
li span  {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 1em;
}
```

Comment: As Rick, you are almost there. Your solution however smashes the vertical alignment, Check my update. +1 for the good effort.

Answer (score 1):

I just updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmfL2643/8/)

I added in your **CSS**

```
ul li span {
    background: url("../img/arrow.png") 0 50% no-repeat;
    background: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/29841/arrow.svg") 0 50% no-repeat;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 12px;
    display: inline-block; // added or it can be inline
}
```

Comment: Rick you are almost there. Your solution however smashes the vertical alignment, Check my update. +1 for the good effort.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED - Final css should be like

```
ul li span {
    background: url("../img/arrow.png") 0 50% no-repeat;
    background: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/29841/arrow.svg") 0 50% no-repeat;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 12px;
}
.dashed {
  border-bottom: 2px dashed #54687a;
  display: block;
  width: 58%;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
li {
    display: table-row;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
li span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 1em;
    width:23%;
}
```

Check the UPDATED demo - http://jsfiddle.net/cmfL2643/21/

Comment: Nice, however it's not what I want exactly. Check my edit please. +1 for the attempt though!

Comment: @gsamaras - please check the updated demo now - http://jsfiddle.net/cmfL2643/15/. Also i will update my answer.

Comment: In your link, Spiropoulos changes line, despite the fact that it belongs to the first child of the list. :/

Comment: @gsamaras - I hope this matches with your output you are looking for -http://jsfiddle.net/cmfL2643/17/.

Comment: I hope this will be exactly what you are looking for - http://jsfiddle.net/cmfL2643/20/ , you can change the width in .dashed & li span to whatever you like , according to your screen & device

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94773/discussion-between-nshah143-and-gsamaras).

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely have better luck with `display: block;` on the list items and `display: inline-block;` on the span. `table-cell` is causing the line to wrap around.

```
li {
    display: display;
    padding: 10px 0px; /* modify as desired */
}
li span {
    width: 50px;    /* Set width as needed so the names line up, even if the span text is different lengths */
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 1em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/cmfL2643/18/